# Nuxt3 swiper module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js, nuxt3

I installed Nuxt3 swiper module
I created carousel and now I want to add navigation with buttons or arrow
I found Way to do it with **useSwiper()** composable but it's undefined

can you tell me what problem shoud be or different approach for create carousel

it's my controller code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WZUW.png)

Comment: Please always [post code as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6225326).  Regarding your issue, it's not clear how your code integrates with the rest of your app.  If you take a look at the [example project](https://stackblitz.com/github/cpreston321/nuxt-swiper/tree/main/examples/swiper-basic?file=app.vue,components%2FSwiperControls.vue) from the documentation, the code matches yours.  Must be something else you've not shown that is incorrect.  Go through the example app and look for things you've done differently.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put swiper in `modules` array in `nuxt.config` after installing it?

Like this:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ['nuxt-swiper']
})
```

I'd recommend reading the `Nuxt-Swiper` [module page](https://nuxt.com/modules/swiper). It has a get started section that you can follow. They also have a working [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/github/cpreston321/nuxt-swiper/tree/main/examples/swiper-basic?file=nuxt.config.ts) using the same composable you're trying to use.